# Search for multiple words PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I've got a simple search PHP script but it only works like that:

Example:
I've got in database "dvd-creator-setup" but if I want to find it I need to write the whole string, like "dvd" or "dvd-creator".
Is it possible to make it work for queries like "dvd creator" or "creator setup"?

```
if (isset($_POST['searchh'])) {
        $searchValue = $_POST['search'];
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            echo "connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error;
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pubfiles WHERE filename LIKE '%$searchValue%'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "File name: <a href=".$row["path"].">" . $row["filename"]. "</a><br />Size: " . $row["size"]. " MB<br/> Uploaded by: " . $row["uploaded_by"]. "<br>-----------------<br>";

            }


        }
```

Comment: No, there is not in SQL. But you can do `WHERE filename LIKE "%dvd%" AND filename LIKE "%creator%"`

Comment: Using string interpolation (`"... '%$searchValue%'"`) exposes you to SQL injections. Imagine someone inputing something like this to your search field - `';DROP TABLE users;`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use full-text index on your `filename` column.

```
alter table pubfiles add fulltext(filename);
```

That allows you to query your filename column using `MATCH() ... AGAINST` syntax.

```
select * from pubfiles where match(filename) against ('dvd creator');
```

This would find  *'dvd'*, *'dvd-creator'*, *'dvd-creator-setup'*, *'creator'*.

There's also a `BOOLEAN MODE`, that will allow you to mark all words as required.

```
select * from pubfiles
  where match(filename) against ('+dvd +creator' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

That would return only *'dvd-creator'* and *'dvd-creator-setup'*.

- Related sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f13a1d/7
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html